# mysql insert with select query to insert multiple rows

Tags: mysql

how to insert multiple rows with insert and select query.

```
INSERT INTO contacts(`studentId`,`contactId`,`firstName`,`lastName`) 
SELECT studentId ,'1234','kavin','kumar' FROM student WHERE sampId='8580',
SELECT studentId, '108','karthi','kumar' FROM student WHERE sampId='5650'
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
INSERT INTO contacts(`studentId`, `contactId`, `firstName`, `lastName`) 
    SELECT studentId, '1234', 'kavin', 'kumar'
    FROM student
    WHERE sampId = '8580'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT studentId, '108', 'karthi', 'kumar'
    FROM student 
    WHERE sampId = '5650';
```

If the id columns are numbers, then do not use single quotes around the values.